# best method lightbox video and image

Tags: jquery, image, video, prototype, lightbox

I'm using JQuery and Prototype in a web page that I'm developing. I'm looking for a way to use Lightbox to play flash movies but doesn't work because I already use Lightbox to display pictures. How can I use Lightbox for displaying images and videos on the same page? If not, what other ways exists?

Answer (score 0):

[PrettyPhoto (jQuery Lightbox)](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) is exactly that you're looking for. There are a lot examples of usage including both galleries with photos and videos in the same page.